# Govee - Automation Feature. Sunrise/Sunset - home city

Tags: smart-home

Anyone used the Govee Automation feature for turning off lights at sunrise and turning on at sunset?

When I try to set it up it asks me for my current city, problem is, I will be in a different timezone during my vacation, will it be going off based on the sunrise and sunset times in my home city?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Smart devices are usually server controlled and rely on the home internet service.  That means your phone could be off or could be on the road and it won't affect the automation.